# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client is not visible from class loader

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, wildfly, jax-ws

I implemented a WSDL Soap service using apache CXF wsdl2Java command. The service is published and running fine but when I am trying to connect to the service via a client in a war deployed in wildfly, I am getting the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client is not visible from class loader". The class which is actually calling the service is loaded using

**CuInterface cuInterface = (CuInterface)Class.forName("com.example.CuImpl", true, this.getClass().getClassLoader());**

The class is loading perfectly but when inside it, I am try to connect to service it is given me the previous error. Please help on this issue.

Comment: Did u figure it out?

Comment: Its the issue with specifically wildfly which use cxf as a part of its webservices module. The wildfly has a parent first policy so it was using g cxf version which it has rather than provided one causing a version mismatch. Wildfly itself accept this issues. What I did, I switched to spring web services. Its pretty easy to use and implement.